# How to increase Excel file Upload Speed in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am uploading an Excel File in Asp.Net MVC. It's working fine on my local machine and live server, but when nearly 2000 records are uploaded it takes more than half an hour to upload the records.

How can I increase the upload speed? I'm using sql server 2012, ASP.NET MVC.

```
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    ds.Clear();
                    string fileExtension =
                                         System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);

                    if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ExcelForUpload/") + Request.Files["file"].FileName;
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                        {

                            System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                        }
                        Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        //connection String for xls file format.
                        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                        {
                            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                            fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        //connection String for xlsx file format.
                        else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                        excelConnection.Open();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        if (dt == null)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }

                        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                        int t = 0;
                        //excel data saves in temp file here.
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            ds.Clear();
                            excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            t++;
                        }
                        OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);


                        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);

                        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                        {
                            // dataAdapter.Dispose();
                            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                        }
                        excelConnection.Close();
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                    }


                    ItemCategory objcategory;
                    Segment objSegment;
                    Size objSize;
                    ProductModel objproductmodel;
                    string tempcategoryname;
                    string tempsegmentname;
                    string tempclassificationname;
                    string productmodelname;
                    int catid;
                    int segid;
                    int classificationId;
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        objcategory = new ItemCategory();
                        objSegment = new Segment();
                        objSize = new Size();
                        objproductmodel = new ProductModel();
                        tempcategoryname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                        if (db.ItemCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.ToLower().Trim() == tempcategoryname.ToLower().Trim()).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            catid = db.ItemCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.ToLower().Trim() == tempcategoryname.ToLower().Trim()).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                            objproductmodel.CategoryID = catid;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objcategory.CategoryName = tempcategoryname;
                            objcategory.IsActive = true;
                            objcategory.CreatedBy = 523;
                            objcategory.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5);
                            db.ItemCategories.Add(objcategory);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            if (db.ItemCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.ToLower().Trim() == tempcategoryname.ToLower().Trim()).Count() > 0)
                            {
                                catid = db.ItemCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.ToLower().Trim() == tempcategoryname.ToLower().Trim()).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                                objproductmodel.CategoryID = catid;
                            }
                        }
                        tempsegmentname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                        if (db.Segments.Where(x => x.SegmentName.ToLower().Trim() == tempsegmentname.ToLower().Trim() && x.CategoryID == objproductmodel.CategoryID).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            segid = db.Segments.Where(x => x.SegmentName.ToLower().Trim() == tempsegmentname.ToLower().Trim() && x.CategoryID == objproductmodel.CategoryID).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                            objproductmodel.SegmentID = segid;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objSegment.SegmentName = tempsegmentname;
                            objSegment.CategoryID = objproductmodel.CategoryID;
                            objSegment.IsActive = true;
                            objSegment.CreatedBy = 523;
                            objSegment.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5);
                            db.Segments.Add(objSegment);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            if (db.Segments.Where(x => x.SegmentName.ToLower().Trim() == tempsegmentname.ToLower().Trim() && x.CategoryID == objproductmodel.CategoryID).Count() > 0)
                            {
                                segid = db.Segments.Where(x => x.SegmentName.ToLower().Trim() == tempsegmentname.ToLower().Trim() && x.CategoryID == objproductmodel.CategoryID).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                                objproductmodel.SegmentID = segid;
                            }
                        }
                        tempclassificationname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                        if (db.Sizes.Where(x => x.SizeName.ToLower().Trim() == tempclassificationname.ToLower().Trim() && x.CategoryID == objproductmodel.CategoryID && x.SegmentID == objproductmodel.SegmentID).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            classificationId = db.Sizes.Where(x => x.SizeName.ToLower().Trim() == tempclassificationname.ToLower().Trim() && x.CategoryID == objproductmodel.CategoryID && x.SegmentID == objproductmodel.SegmentID).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                            objproductmodel.SizeID = classificationId;
                        }

                    }
                }
                transection.Commit();

                ds.Clear();
                return Json(new { MessageType = 1, Message = "Record successfully inserted." });
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transection.Rollback();

                return Json(new { MessageType = 0, Message = ex.Message });
            }
```

Comment: Increase your internet speed - specifically the Upload speed, that's the only thing you can do to speed up the upload process. Do a speedTest on [beta.speedtest.net](http://beta.speedtest.net) and see the result.

Comment: on 2000 records it takes half hour for Uploading On my local system where No internet is involved

Comment: The issue seems to be what you are doing with this file and not the upload itself. Try to find which part of the process is slow.

Comment: Yes, it's true.. try using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and output markers to console like Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.Tostring() + " Upload Begin"). This is a good way to see what the bottleneck is.. That being said Excel interop causes lag issues when you do cell level work.. Try not using Excel interop, perhaps use a datatable then export to excel